# Getting the newest post from a topic using ICriteria (Nhibernate)

Tags: nhibernate, group-by, subquery, icriteria

In a forum, I want to list the most recent posts from each topic.
In SQL I can do a subquery with group by Topic taking Max(Post.Date) and then make an inner join with the Posts table to get the latest Post record from each Topic.
How can I reproduce this in ICriteria?

DETAIL: The Topic class have NO Posts property.

TARGET SQL:
SELECT Post.*
FROM Posts, (SELECT IdTopic, MAX(DATE) AS Date FROM Posts GROUP BY IdTopic) AS MaxDates
WHERE MaxDates.IdTopic = Posts.IdTopic AND MaxDates.Date = Posts.Date

Tks[]

Patrick Coelho

Comment: Can you update your post with the SQL that you're looking to have ICriteria generate for you? Also, it would be helpful if you provide your schema, or at least the relevant portions of it.

Comment: @cs Updated with target SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using CreateCriteria. This is explained very well by [Ayende Rahien](http://ayende.com/blog/4023/nhibernate-queries-examples).

**Edit** changed to address OP's comments

I'm on shaky ground here, but this may get you started:

```
DetatchedCriteria posts = DetachedCriteria.For<Post>("p")
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("p.IdPost"));        
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("t.IdPost", "p.IdPost"));

DetachedCriteria postMax = DetachedCriteria.For<Post>, "p2")
    .SetProjection(Projections.Max("Date"));

var topics Session.CreateCriteria<Topic>("t")
    .Add(Subqueries.Select(postMax))
    .Add(Subqueries.Exists(posts)).List<Topic>();
```

Comment: Good solution but unfortunately, the Topic class does not have a Posts property.

Comment: @Steve The Post class have a Topic property.

Comment: @Patrick A curious set up. What are the fields in each table that are used to relate to each other?

Comment: @Steve In database is referenced by the field IdPost

Comment: @Steve Subqueries.Select -> Subqueries does not contain Select method.

Comment: @Patrick What version of nHibernate are you using? I use version 3 and it is there.

Comment: @Steve My NHibernate version is 2.0.1.4000. Any other solution?